# Is there a possibility of there ever being a PHP.NET?

Tags: .net, php, clr

Sorry if this is a silly and/or stupid question but... Will there ever be, or would it even be possible to have a PHP.NET? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

It seemed to me that one of the main points of .NET was that you could write your code in one of a bunch of the .NET languages and have it compile into CLR. Could this happen with PHP, or is there something about PHP that makes this impossible? Or is there more political reasons?

Comment: Well, there's a COBOL port for .Net, so never say never :)

Comment: So true... Never say never, anything is possible, kind of goes contrary to most of Microsoft's web products though

Comment: Surprisingly, Microsoft has as of late actually been putting some resources into making PHP run well on Windows.  They even make it trivial to install.

Comment: Oh God, I hope not.  Then there'll be no shutting up the PHP guys about how "Microsoft costs too much."

Comment: When was it difficult to install PHP on Windows?

Comment: Wow ... @Darrel... you're quite right... http://php.iis.net/ That is quite an amazing promotion of PHP by Microsoft. I expected minor adjustments on their end.. but that appears to be a full integration with IIS. Its good to see MS opening up to other products and offerring extendibility rather than internal solutions. I guess Apache must have rattled their cage abit.

Comment: Have you ever tried to compile PHP under Windows lately ?

Comment: Why would you want to? Windows isn't about having to compile your own binaries...

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft has started a big move on PhP some month ago (for the tools part, the development must have started sooner). They're not opening to new products, they just want to gobble a rather good eco-system to make it theirs.

Comment: The day PHP comes to .NET, i'll eat my keyboard.

Comment: [The whole of WordPress compiled to .NET Core and a NuGet package with PeachPie](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWholeOfWordPressCompiledToNETCoreAndANuGetPackageWithPeachPie.aspx). [Using C# in PHP and Vice Versa](https://www.peachpie.io/2019/02/using-c-in-php-and-vice-versa.html). That's solid evidence. Interesting possibilities - if your business has a foot in both worlds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an aside:

I don't believe .Net support for PHP would be a great idea.

I use PHP every day of my life. It's not because I like the language (it's a collection of mismatched functions with very little OO support), but rather because it's the best tool for the job.

PHP has a lightweight feel and one can do almost anything in a few easy lines. It's string handling is effortless, and support is ubiquitous. Array handling is great, too.

I feel that if PHP joined the .Net CLR I would not be tempted to switch over to use it. If one wanted to work with .Net one would do better to use a nicer, better structured language, such as C#.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying here. That you don't think it would be a great idea because you wouldn't be tempted to switch over? As for it being lightweight, the .NET has the forthcoming DLR which wouldn't impose any heavy burdens on the language like running in the regular CLR would.

Comment: I think that the PHP is not a well structured language and wouldn't add anything to the .Net framework. PHP is more of a vast set of useful functions, the .Net class libraries will already provide most of this. So PHP .Net will essentially be a poor OO implementation with some bad syntax... and no additional benefits. Of course PHP is my web language of choice, but I argue that it doesn't suit .Net.

Comment: I don't agree 1) You can compile standard PHP to .NET and then call it from C# or deploy it more comfortably on Windows - in this case you don't loose the simplicity of PHP at all. 2) For some enterprise projects (that mix .NET and PHP for some reason), having the ability to integrate .NET and PHP smoothly is a great advantage. (Phalanger mentioned below supports both modes)

Comment: IMHO, the benefit of porting PHP into .NET is to transition the vast body of php code and experience into an environment with more long-term potential. A stepping stone to lower the cost of integrating existing web projects into a unified all-platform codebase that is based around best-of-breed solutions. Way better than what will otherwise win, which is using web technologies everywhere (HTML5+Javascript apps - Stepping backwards 20+ years in software design, no thanks). Granted, the problem isn't solved until extends all the way to the client browser, but this is a significant step closer.

Comment: To clarify my POV: Have existing php code and programmers. Hoping to transition to Razor Components in .Net Core 3, to align better with WPF and Xamarin Forms app code bases. Can't justify rewriting all existing web code. Hoping PeachPie makes it possible to migrate incrementally. TBD.

Answer (score 7):

Someone has actually already begun working on just such a thing

http://www.codeplex.com/Phalanger

http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php

Comment: The guys that developed Phalanger are now developing peachpie at https://www.peachpie.io/

Answer (score 3):

I would say that it is unlikely as that there is ASP.net, but I would not say never because of Python.NET or IronPython. There is already one attempt called [Phalanger.](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=Phalanger) From the looks of the [official wiki](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php), its a serious development effort.

Comment: The guys that developed Phalanger are now developing peachpie at https://www.peachpie.io/

Answer (score 3):

Actually it exists. It's not called PHP.NET, but [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com)(http://phalanger.codeplex.com). It compiles PHP code into MSIL instructions.

It allows to run PHP application in so called legacy mode (and you can benefit from a faster running time since it's compiled), and if you want to use CLR features that are not present in PHP you can turn on PHP/CLR compiler extensions.

There is also so called Pure mode where PHP langauge is modified to behave more like C# or Visual Basic.

I think combining PHP and .NET is great idea, since you can make the best of both worlds. From PHP it would fast development and deployment process, steep learning curve and there are lots of great PHP open-source applications. On the .NET side, verifiable ISO standartized environment, peformance, managed secure code, advanced development tools,...

Comment: The guys that developed Phalanger are now developing peachpie at https://www.peachpie.io/

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there's a possibility. [Python runs in the CLR](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=IronPython), after all.

Side note: PHP is now a one-click install for IIS, so if you're waiting to bring PHP into your Microsoft stack, go ahead and give it a try. MS is even working on a [PHP bytecode cache for Windows](http://www.iis.net/expand/WinCacheForPhp).

Answer (score 1):

Once this is in I don't see why not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime

Answer (score 1):

The CLR is essentially a virtual machine, so things are compiled to it essentially the same way C code is compiled to x86 or PowerPC or arm or whatever.

There is an implementation of python that compiles to .NET assemblies, there's also COBOL, and a few others. No technical reason PHP couldn't be done the same and executed by the CLR in IIS.

Comment: Compilation is the trivial part; porting the huge library of builting PHP functions using god knows what kind of dirty C tricks is a rather different matter...

Answer (score 0):

.NET is a framework that is based on a number of technologies such as CLR and provides an extensive collection well-organized class libraries that are suitable for almost all conceivable functions that are used in Web applications. In addition, it allows you to easily create components that extend the framework.

Although PHP has similar properties, such as PEAR libraries, PHP and ASP.NET are not really identical, because the .NET framework ab ovo on an OOP paradigm and OOP-based approaches, and PHP is not. This difference is most evident in the way, is how to access classes and objects in PHP and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to the [jsc project](http://jsc.sf.net) which will convert MSIL to php source for you.

This will enable you to write C# code in visual studio and run it on an inexpensive php server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two are totally different, they are in competition with each other. Both will try to be good at their ends. So i dont think there is going to be anything as such in the future. However, you can use PHP inside of Visual Studio, there are plugins available for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP have got suspiciously pally with Windows... it doesn't seem impossible

And besides [PHP.**NET**](http://www.php.net)

Answer (score 0):

Well PHP is good as is already. Even if it does become PHP.NET I doubt it will be done by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

you could develop php on windows to use windows functions, and ultimately call on .NET objects. I believe apache now allows php to call on native windows calls/functions and .NET functions/classes/objects, provided you have the right settings turned on.

as for .NET adapting php syntax, i think some people are trying to do this, aside from the existing attempts.