# How I can turn PHP into .NET?

Tags: php, .net, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm trying to make a program that can turn something into something else.

I do not want to create a second file from the first. What I want is something that receives the request for a page to access the php file and after playing out as if it were an aspx file.

For example if the url requested http://www.address.com/phpexample/ run the index.php that is in that folder and then send the result to interpret the CLR for this show it as a file index.aspx

An engineer came to school and showed us his project that does just that. He said that we must first obtain a string representing the code and interpreted by php and send it to the net CLR to be shown as if it were an aspx file. I know it's possible to do because he did.

The problem is not how to get the chain or as you would to send it to the CLR. I've been reading a lot and still have not found something that gives me the slightest clue. It's for my final project programming. Please if I can give you all the information known in this topic will be eternally grateful.

Comment: Not enough information. Not really a question.

Comment: How does the program get the PHP code in `index.php`? Should I assume that it resides on the same server as `http://www.address.com/phpexample/` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to read this either. It probably has to do with URL routing, but how?

Comment: @Pekka: Actually, I think this is a program on a server that receives a request for a PHP file, then converts the PHP to .NET, sends the .NET code to the CLR, gets the result, and returns that result. This could be easily done if you can invoke PHP from .NET. I imagine something like this in the .NET-side: `return PHPProcessor.ProcessPHPCode(incomingPHPString);` ;)

Comment: @Pekka: *Why* someone would want this is a little harder for me to understand...

Comment: @Frustrated that would have been my next question :) Maybe to add a .NET generated  HTML wrapper around the result of some PHP code?... But there would be *much* easier ways to achieve that.

Comment: This might shed more light: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1883956/78782

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for (the question is kind of vague) but you can compile PHP to .NET using [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/).

Answer (score 0):

what you want (i think) is a ReWrite rule in htaccess

[look here for some tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

That will make it seem to the enduser that it is a aspx page, but in reality it will be php.