# ORM for PHP like .NET Entity Framework

Tags: php, .net, database, entity-framework, orm

I'm a .NET developer and new in PHP. I want to know, is there a ORM for PHP like the Entity Framework in the Microsoft .NET Framework?

Are there any utility applications to make working with data faster and easier?

Comment: Not sure about that, but you might be interested in a PHP.NET http://stackoverflow.com/q/1883956/78782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend you take a look at Doctrine ORM. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) can generate your table to PHP class mappings using YAML, which is similar to NHibernate's mappings using XML. Doctrine also provides command line tools to rebuild aspects of your data layer based on changes to either your schema, the models themselves or the database tables you're abstracting over.

I've only really looked at NHibernate, not used it. So I wouldn't claim to know precisely how well the two ORMs approaches cross-over; I'm sure a quick glance through their [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en) would help you reach a better conclusion.

Comment: hmm? seems choice is hard :-?

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative that implements a modern data persistence approach in PHP can be found in [Agile Data](https://github.com/atk4/data). It used to be part of Agile Toolkit (http://www.agiletoolkit.org), but now it's refactored into a stand-alone framework.

Comment: wow from the documentation this seems a beast

Comment: sarcasm ? or really.. Its not loading for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like Doctrine, instead I use [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/download.html), which is light weight (much lighter than Doctrine).

I find it to be more efficient and easy. Since it is used with CodeIgniter, the CodeIgniterand DataMapper's transactions are same.

In DataMapper you do not have to create fields in your model by hand. So if you add any fields in the table, you don't have to change your Models.