# Can ASP.NET module be uploaded on PHP domain?

Tags: c#, php, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a website which is in PHP. Now, I am trying to publish a separate admin panel (which is in ASP.NET) on the same server but in different virtual directory.

Can this work?

Comment: PHP.NET would be nice in your situation http://stackoverflow.com/q/1883956/78782 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web server is Windows running IIS, then yes, you can have ASP.NET and PHP co-existing on the same server.

You will have problems if you intend to share anything between them -- eg cookies, and session data; you'll have to effectively keep them separate and provide separate logins, etc for them.

On the other hand, if your server isn't Windows, or isn't running IIS - say if you're running a Linux server with Apache - then you won't be able to install ASP.NET, since it is tied to that platform.

[EDIT] This is a discussion on the official Microsoft IIS forum, where the same question is asked, and the positive answer is given: http://forums.iis.net/t/1154462.aspx

Also, this might help: http://www.joshholmes.com/blog/2010/11/11/asp-net-and-php-on-iis-together/

Comment: `...server isn't Windows, or isn't running IIS - say if you're running a Linux server with Apache - then you won't be able to install ASP.NET...`  That's not _entirely_ true, there is  [Mono (and Mod_Mono)](http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono).  As of 2.8, Mono supports ASP.NET 4.0, and MVC 2.

Comment: @galador - yes, fair enough, though if I'm pedantic about it, if it's Mono then it wouldn't actually be .NET...  ;)  But in any case, looking at the OP's previous questions, my guess is that they've got a Windows server, so its likely a moot point.

Comment: when I publish my ASP.NET module it publishes successfully but when I try to access it I get error 404. I have cross checked the path twice but to no help.

Comment: Troubleshooting 101 - Put a basic default html page in the virtual directory and try and get to it. If it(the html page) comes up but your aspx page does not then you are configured incorrectly for asp.net. If it does not come up then your path is wrong.